# EC2 instance t2.micro unable to install docker

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-ec2

My kernal version:

```sh
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-171 ~]$ uname -a
Linux ip-172-31-15-171 4.14.158-101.185.amzn1.x86_64 #1 SMP Tue Dec 24 03:25:32 UTC 2019 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

What I tried, but only get:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-171 ~]$ sudo yum install -y docker
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package docker.x86_64 0:19.03.6ce-3.57.amzn1 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: runc >= 1.0.0 for package: docker-19.03.6ce-3.57.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: containerd >= 1.3.2 for package: docker-19.03.6ce-3.57.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: xfsprogs for package: docker-19.03.6ce-3.57.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: pigz for package: docker-19.03.6ce-3.57.amzn1.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: libseccomp.so.2()(64bit) for package: docker-19.03.6ce-3.57.amzn1.x86_64
--> Running transaction check
---> Package containerd.io.x86_64 0:1.2.13-3.1.el7 will be installed
--> Processing Dependency: container-selinux >= 2:2.74 for package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
--> Processing Dependency: systemd for package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64
---> Package libseccomp.x86_64 0:2.3.1-2.4.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package pigz.x86_64 0:2.3.3-1.6.amzn1 will be installed
---> Package xfsprogs.x86_64 0:4.5.0-18.23.amzn1 will be installed
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: containerd.io-1.2.13-3.1.el7.x86_64 (docker-ce-stable)
           Requires: container-selinux >= 2:2.74
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I have googled a lot, someone says that ami does not support systemctl. I have no idea to figure it out. 
For container-selinux, I tried this, but it does not work too.

```
sudo yum install -q -y http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/extras/x86_64/Packages/container-selinux-2.107-1.el7_6.noarch.rpm
```

I also tried the command provided by [amazon official document](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/docker-basics.html)

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-171 ~]$ sudo amazon-linux-extras install docker
sudo: amazon-linux-extras: command not found
```

Try to install it:

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-15-171 ~]$ sudo yum install -y amazon-linux-extras
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                                                              | 2.1 kB  00:00:00     
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                           | 2.5 kB  00:00:00     
No package amazon-linux-extras available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

No package, what's wrong with this instance!

Frustrated. I hope for your help, please.

Comment: Please note that Stack Overflow is for programming questions and not general computing issues. Please review [What topics can I ask here?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) for more details. Question may be appropriate for [Server Fault](http://serverfault.com) or [Unix & Linux](http://unix.stackexchange.com) but do check their help before posting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most likely reason for the issue is the use of Amazon Linux 1 (amzn1). Amazon Linux 1 uses `sysvinit`, instead of `systemd`.

The recommended solution is to use Amazon Linux 2 which does support `systemd`

Comment: With amzn1, is it possible to install docker?

Comment: Maybe there is, I don't know. Your question does not indicate that using Amazon Linux 1 is a requirement. AL1 will be only supported to the end of [this year](https://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/). So if not now, then have to switch to AL2 anyway in near future.